# Merge two cells based on criteria

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an iOS app which has a `UITableView` displaying patient records. Say for instance that I have a database table with 3 columns: `Patient Id`, `Blood Pressure` and `Timestamp` (auto generated).

Now each `UITableViewCell` contains data from a row in the database table, say for instance I have table with values:

```
Pat Id    BP 
1         100
2         101
1         105
```

So my `UITableView` will have 3 cells, but the patient records are sent multiple times according to time, so each patient will have multiple records.

I want to group the cells based on `Patient ID` and display all of the values in a detail view controller.

Eg:
 in the table view I want to see this

First UItableviewcell:
 Pat ID 1
Name ralf

Second UItableviewcell
Pat ID 2
Name George

Eve if Pat Id 1 has 100 records in database in tableview I want all the records grouped into one, now if I have 100 records for patient ID 1, I get 100 cells in tableview wit patient ID 1.

Instead I just want one cell with the 100 values grouped and once I click on the cell it should go to detailviewcontroller displaying the 100 values. Thanks

Comment: Merge the cells? Or merge the records in your model (when you receive an update)?

Comment: So what do you want to see in this table view (not the detail view controller)?

Comment: You should create cells for header and cell for every record row. Your rows counter will be [number of records] + 1 (for header cell).

Comment: I want to group records in my model, for one patient I want just one cell not muliple cells

Comment: @anatoliy_v, I don't get that

Comment: @rdelmar I updated the question please look at it thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is what section are made for in a tableview.
Instead of the ABC you can list the patients id or Name instead. You cold even customize the section header to display more details. Lets say a picture, the name and the id.

Comment: I want to group cells, can you get that?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to advise very specifically you without knowing what your current data structure looks like. Basically, you need to build a new data structure from your current one. I think a dictionary would be best, where the keys were the patient IDs or names, and the values would be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary having keys for name, blood pressure, timestamp, and anything else you have. The table view would then be populated with the array you get from the dictionary's allKeys method, and when you select a cell, you would pass the value of the dictionary whose key is displayed in that cell to your detail table view.

Comment: Do I need to use a dictionary? I am populating tableview from my sqlite database. Actually I am not too sure how clear I am, the thing I want to do is first display a tableview with grouped patients then I want that to navigate to other tableview with that specific patient list and finally to a detailviewcontroller. Please let me know how to make this more clear, Thanks for the help though will check the dictionary

Comment: @user2856757, no, you don't have to use a dictionary, you can arrange the data however you think works best for you. I've never used an sqlite database directly, so I don't know how to advise you on that.